# Do you know how to create a category only for the custom-post-type?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

I mean, that not appear in posts or another custom-post-type, that only belongs to a specific custom-post-type.

```
function custom_post_type() {
$args = array(
  'label' => __( 'Post Type', 'munich' ),
  'description' => __( 'Post Type Description', 'munich' ),
  'labels' => $labels,
  'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 
  'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields' ),
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'public' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'show_in_menu' => true,
);

  register_post_type( 'a_post_type', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );

function custom_taxonomy() {
    $args = array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'public' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
      'show_tagcloud' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'a_taxonomy', array( 'a_post_type' ), $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy', 0 );
```

I expect that in my dashboard, the category that I created in the specific custom-post-type, appears only in that category.

Ex: custom-post-type->'food', categories->'chinese', 'french', etc.

If I use other custom-post-type, like 'sports' doesn't include the categories 'chinese', 'french', etc.

Comment: what is the question here??

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete, first you'd create the post type like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom21432_post_type', 0 );
function custom21432_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => __( 'Food' ),
        'singular_name'       => __( 'Food'),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Food'),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Food'),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Food'),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Food'),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Food'),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New'),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Food'),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Food'),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Food'),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found'),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash')
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Food'),
        'description'         => __( 'Our custom type'),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields'),
        'public'              => true,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'yarpp_support'       => true,
        'taxonomies'          => array('post_tag'),
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page'
);
    register_post_type( 'food_ctype', $args );
}
```

Then you create a taxonomy and assign it to the post type like this

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom21432__taxonomy', 0 );
function custom21432__taxonomy() {

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Origin', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Origin', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Origin' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Origin' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Origin' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Origin:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Origin' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Origin' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Origin' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Origin Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Origin' ),
  );    

  register_taxonomy('origin_taxonomy',array('food_ctype'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'foodorigin' ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: Hi @Lude, if this answer is helped sorting your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.